# CAShapeLayer with CIFilters

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cashapelayer, cifilter

I would like to apply CIFilter to CAShapeLayer.filters. 
Is this correct assumption how to do this:

- create CAShapeLayer
- create CGImage or UIImage from CAShapeLayer
- create CIFilter with CGImage or UIImage
- add CIFilter to CAShapeLayer.filters

To create CGImage from CAShapeLayer I used CAShapeLayer.contents but in my case the *contents* is nil, also if I render CAShapeLayer to image context I could not get the image.

```
override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        if(self.shapeLayer == nil && self.path != nil && self.pathOriginationSize != CGSizeZero)
        {
            let scaleFactor = self.scaleFactor(self.pathOriginationSize, targetSize: self.bounds.size)

            _scaledPath = UIBezierPath(CGPath: self.path.CGPath)
            _scaledPath.lineWidth = self.path.lineWidth
            _scaledPath.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor.x, scaleFactor.y))
            _scaledPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round

            self.shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            self.shapeLayer.path = _scaledPath.CGPath
            self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = self.path.lineWidth

            let imageSize = CGPathGetBoundingBox(_scaledPath.CGPath).size

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            self.shapeLayer.renderInContext(context!)
            _ = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            let cgImage = self.shapeLayer.contents as! CGImageRef

            let inputImage = CIImage(CGImage: cgImage)

            let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIZoomBlur")
            blurFilter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            blurFilter?.setDefaults()
            self.shapeLayer.filters = [blurFilter!]
            self.shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = true

            self.layer.addSublayer(self.shapeLayer)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CALayer.filters` is not implemented on iOS.

There's no need to use a `CAShapeLayer` in this case (since you can't use `filters`). You can just create a `CGImage` from the `UIBezierPath` (as you're doing; just `stroke` and/or `fill` the path rather than calling `renderInContext`). Then use `apply` the `CIFilter` to the result, create a `CGImage` and assign that to `contents`. (From your above code, you seem to understand how to do all those things, so I'm not writing it out here.)

Comment: Hey Rob! Do you happen to know if there is an efficient way to filter CALayer as CALayer.filters is not working on iOS?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "efficient" here. But if the above is not fast enough for you, you should be digging deeper into Core Image. I'd start with the most recent WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/510/

Comment: Sorry for not explaining. We are developing a video-processing app. Part of the app is applying filters to the video. Using the higher level AVFoundation API, I can access the video frames as a CALayer object. But using a bit more complex API I can access the video frames by a CIImage object. So basically I'm asking if using this method is a lot SLOWER than using the CIImage mechanism (with a complexity downside).. What do you think?

Comment: I'd never do video this way myself; you want to stay in the Core Image space as much as you can, and convert to Core Graphics as late and infrequently as possible (if ever). But you'd have to test it to know if this approach were actually slow. I would stay in Core Image for control, not performance itself (so when you have a performance problem, you can fix it without redesigning your whole system). Apple typically builds their higher-level frameworks on top of lower-level frameworks very well, so you can't guess what performance hit you'll take. You have to test it.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll take a look at what you've sent. Have a great day!